# Deleting all records CloudKit every day from a particular record type

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

So I want to wipe every record for a particular record type every day. So basically, I want the data to be wiped at 12:00 AM so that it will be fresh for the next day. How would I go about doing this? Is this something that I could set up in the CloudKit dashboard or will I have to set this up programmatically?

Answer (score 12):

Deleting records from the dashboard is a lot of work if you need to delete multiple records.

The best workaround is by creating a separate recordType that will contain one record for every day. Then in the records that you want deleted for that day set up a CKReference to that particular day record and set its action to CKReferenceAction.DeleteSelf

After that you only have to remove the day record and all related records will be removed. Removing that one record could easily be done from the dashboard or you could create functionality in your app or you could create a 2nd app for administrative actions.

Answer (score 12):

```
func deleteAllRecords()
{
    let publicDatabase: CKDatabase = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase

    // fetch records from iCloud, get their recordID and then delete them
    var recordIDsArray: [CKRecordID] = []

    let operation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: nil, recordIDsToDelete: recordIDsArray)
    operation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = {
        (savedRecords: [CKRecord]?, deletedRecordIDs: [CKRecordID]?, error: NSError?) in
        print("deleted all records")
    }
    
    publicDatabase.add(operation)
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a limit on how many records you can delete in one batch when you do it this way?

Comment: For some reason this is not working for me. When I fetch from the database later, all the records that were supposed to have been deleted are still there.

Comment: I'm getting "Account temporarily unavailable due to bad or missing auth token" error.

Comment: Account temporarily unavailable - SOLVED! Turns out we need to log in into simulator settings (if we run this on simulator) with valid Apple id.

Answer (score 8):

Try something like this:

```
let publicDb = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase

let query = CKQuery(recordType: "RECORD TYPE", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray: nil))
publicDb.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { (records, error) in

    if error == nil {

        for record in records! {

            publicDb.deleteRecordWithID(record.recordID, completionHandler: { (recordId, error) in

                if error == nil {

                    //Record deleted

                }

            })

        }

    }

}
```

"RECORD TYPE" should be your record type. Hope this helps.

Comment: this is way slower due to the for loop, if you have more then 3-5 entries this will take longer then a minute!! you should use a batch delete like this:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/36414506/530884

Comment: That loop is starting several asynchronous operations one after the other! How many concurrent connections are you willing to have? I would serialize it somehow.

Comment: You also can fetch only `recordName` in `desiredKeys` so the operation will be faster. Other fields are not needed for deletion and their data will disappear anyway.

Answer (score 4):

this code able to delete any amount of records

```
import CloudKit

class iCloudDelete {

    private let cloudDB: CKDatabase
    private var recordIDsToDelete = [CKRecordID]()
    private var onAllQueriesCompleted : (()->())?

    public var resultsLimit = 10 // default is 100

    init(cloudDB: CKDatabase){
        self.cloudDB = cloudDB
    }

    func delete(query: CKQuery, onComplete: @escaping ()->Void) {
        onAllQueriesCompleted = onComplete
        add(queryOperation: CKQueryOperation(query: query))
    }

    private func add(queryOperation: CKQueryOperation) {
        queryOperation.resultsLimit = resultsLimit
        queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = queryDeleteCompletionBlock
        queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = recordFetched
        cloudDB.add(queryOperation)
    }

    private func queryDeleteCompletionBlock(cursor: CKQueryCursor?, error: Error?) {
        print("-----------------------")
        delete(ids: recordIDsToDelete) {
            self.recordIDsToDelete.removeAll()

            if let cursor = cursor {
                self.add(queryOperation: CKQueryOperation(cursor: cursor))
            } else {
                self.onAllQueriesCompleted?()
            }
        }
    }

    private func recordFetched(record: CKRecord) {
        print("RECORD fetched: \(record.recordID.recordName)")
        recordIDsToDelete.append(record.recordID)
    }

    private func delete(ids: [CKRecordID], onComplete: @escaping ()->Void) {
        let delete = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: nil, recordIDsToDelete: ids)
        delete.completionBlock = {
            onComplete()
        }
        cloudDB.add(delete)
    }
 }
```